# Accessing data on drive that was initialized as a GPT

Tags: linux, windows, macos, hard-drive, hfs

I have a USB drive that only had a /dev/disk1 that I could mount by `mount -t hfs /dev/disk1 /Volumes/usb` on a Mac drive. For the life of me I could not get it mount or be read on Windows regardless of the tools I used.

Windows decided to initialize the drive as a GPT so now I can't mount it under Mac and I see `/dev/disk1` and `/dev/disk1s1` is there anyway to undo what Windows did so I can access the data?

I should also mention that I did not create any partitions. I simply accessed the disk from Windows Disk Management and let Windows make it GPT thinking it would finally allow me to view the drive after all the other software I tried would not show the drive.

EDIT:
So I did some more research and it looks like Apple releases APFS a new version over HFS. Could that have been why I as not able to access the USB drive at all on Windows was due to the new file system?

Comment: I don't know how to undo what Windows has done.  I believe that initializing the drive has removed the HFS filesystem, although I cannot prove that.  When I want to transfer a USB drive between MS Windows, Mac OS X and Linux, I format the drive as FAT32 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#FAT32

Comment: To expand upon the good suggestion from @StandardEyre , I usually format my external USB drives in **exFAT** format.  It is compatible with both Windows and OS X, but it doesn't have the 4 GB file size limitation found in FAT32.  [What’s the Difference Between FAT32, exFAT, and NTFS?](http://www.howtogeek.com/235596/whats-the-difference-between-fat32-exfat-and-ntfs/)

Comment: " I simply accessed the disk from Windows Disk Management and let Windows make it GPT thinking it would finally allow me to view the drive after all the other software I tried would not show the drive." - When you did, your what I will assume was a OS X compatible filesystem, was removed.  You should be able to use OS X tools to recover the data provided you have not replaced it with anything.